# Simple SQL math operation gives incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am running into an issue with a simple SQL math operation of `qty * price` is returning an incorrect value.

This is SQL server 2005. Compatibility is set to 80 for 2000 SQL server.

Any help on understanding why I am having the problem shown below

For example: 
Transaction Table:

```
  id     price   qty
  1      2.77    20.00
  1      2.77    25.00
  1      2.77    10.00
  2      0.10    50.00
  2      0.10    80.00
  3      0.10    50.00
  3      0.10    60.00
```

SQL

```
Select id, price, qty, (qty * price) from transact
```

The actual problem was this and it was my fault :(

```
Select id, CAST(price AS DECIMAL(5,2)), qty, (qty * price) from transact
```

Returns the following:

```
  id  price  qty    Total
  1   2.77   20.00   55.400000    Correct
  1   2.77   25.00   69.250000    Correct
  1   2.77   10.00   27.700000    Correct
  2   0.10   50.00    4.800000    Should be 5.0000
  2   0.10   80.00    7.680000    Should be 8.0000
  2   0.10   50.00    5.050000    Should be 5.0000
  2   0.10   60.00    6.060000    Should be 6.0000
  3   39.00   1.00   39.000000    Correct
  3   39.00   2.00   78.000000    Correct
  3   39.00   3.00  117.000000    Correct
```

Comment: I'm with James on this one.  Script your table and post the create table statement.  I would suggest Price should be money and depending on what you are selling it is more than likely that qty should be an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You price is being rounded somewhere. The select you are running is not showing the actual price.

```
select round(0.096, 2) price, 0.096 * 50.00 total
```

Result:

```
price    total
0.10     4.80000
```

Comment: @all_posts You were all correct.  I really try to analyse better before i post issues.  I was in a time crunch, and it always the littlest thing that will trip you up.  While cleaning up my table and sql to be able to post, the price column was cast(price as decimal(5,2)) and I over looked that not being in my math of price * qty.  Thank you for the posts, and sorry for asking a question that i should have caught in the first place.  I was told a long time ago, when you try to blame the compiler, point the finger back at yourself....